# Error when i try to use if in the for loop in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop

I have a problem when i try to run a for loop in a for loop.

I try to make 24 files with ips with step of 10.

To explain more in the first file i need to have all ips that ends betwen 1-10 and second 11 to 20 and so on.

I try to use:

```
    for i in {1..240}
    do
    for r in {1..24}
    do
        if [ "$i" -le "$r0" ]
        then
            echo "4.2.2.$i" >> "server-$r"
        fi
    done
done
```

The error i recived is when i run bash -xv script_name:

```
script_name: line 5: [: : integer expression expected
+ for r in '{1..24}'
+ '[' 240 -le '' ']'
script_name: line 5: [: : integer expression expected
+ for r in '{1..24}'
+ '[' 240 -le '' ']'
script_name: line 5: [: : integer expression expected
```

The filenames are server-$r, ie server-1,server-2, so on until server-24

Any advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the following:

```
if [ "$i" -le "$r0" ]
```

You don't have a variable `r0`, which causes the error.  Say:

```
if [ "$i" -le "${r}0" ]
```

instead so as to avoid ambiguity.

---

Since you wanted to *multiply* the number by 10, you could write it mathematically as:

```
if [ "$i" -le $((r*10)) ]
```

or even

```
(( i <= r*10 ))
```

Comment: The `$((...))` is redundant inside `((...))`: `(( i <= r*10 ))`.

Comment: It's woking, but in the files i found progresiv all the ips, not just those 10 ips. in 1st are 1 to 10 in secod 1 to 20 and the final 1 to 240. How can i limit just 10 of the ips.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the bash-native / idiomatic way to do things anyhow.

```
for ((i=1; i<=240; i++)); do
    for ((r=1; r<=24; r++)); do
        if (( i <= (r * 10) )); then
            echo "4.2.2.$i"
        fi
    done >"server-$r"
done
```

Opening the `server-$r` file only once per value of `$r` is far more efficient than opening it for each individual `echo` (otherwise you're opening and closing the file every time it needs to be accessed), and using expansions such as `{1..3}` is inflexible (only supported with literal numbers, not variables) and expands to a wordlist that gets iterated over, thus using more memory than using a C-style for loop.